# Remove div from html content using PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I have an existing PHP app that generates this div element:

```
<div style='position:fixed;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:#f00;text-align:center'>
<div class='asdthjeme'>Designed by 
<a href='http://blabla.com/' target='_blank'>dnfdjf</a></div></div>
```

I am trying to remove above div element from HTML content using PHP, but it doesn't work for me
My php code:

```
$text = '<div style='position:fixed;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:#f00;text-align:center'>
    <div class='asdthjeme'>Designed by 
    <a href='http://blabla.com/' target='_blank'>dnfdjf</a></div></div>';
echo preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $text);
```

Thanks in your help guys!

Comment: ... What? You are showing us the variable with the text, not what you have tried in order to remove it, besides, why not just remove it from the first php file?

Comment: it is generated automatically

Answer (score 0):

You can't use single quotes if your string is *enclosed* in single quotes.

Either escape them with `\` or use different quotes.

```
$text = "<div style='position:fixed;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:#f00;text-align:center'>
<div class='asdthjeme'>Designed by 
<a href='http://blabla.com/' target='_blank'>dnfdjf</a></div></div>";
```

or

```
$text = '<div style=\'position:fixed;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:#f00;text-align:center\'>
<div class=\'asdthjeme\'>Designed by 
<a href=\'http://blabla.com/\' target=\'_blank\'>dnfdjf</a></div></div>';
```

Comment: I forgot to add tis piece of code in my PHP section :      echo preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $text);

Comment: What are you trying to remove??

Comment: I want to remove: <div style='position:fixed;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:#f00;text-align:center'>
<div class='asdthjeme'>Designed by 
<a href='http://blabla.com/' target='_blank'>dnfdjf</a></div></div>

Comment: This regex is for you then: `/(\<div.*\<\/div\>)/gs`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$text = '<div style="position:fixed;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;background:#f00;text-align:center">
<div class="asdthjeme">Designed by 
<a href="http://blabla.com/" target="_blank">dnfdjf</a></div></div>';
```

Comment: I forgot to add tis piece of code in my PHP section :      echo preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $text);